# Why is this custom bisect function on endless loop?

Tags: python, bisect

I have a long script in which I was initially using bisect in. This was part of it (worked perfectly fine and as intended):

```
portfolios = [[1], [0.9], [0.8], [0.7], [0.6]] #Fills up list to avoid "index out of range" error later on in code
add_sharpe = [sharpe, name_a, weight_a, exchange_a, name_b, weight_b, exchange_b, name_c, weight_c, exchange_c]
for x in portfolios:
    if sharpe > x[0]:
        sharpes =  [i[0] for i in portfolios]
        if name_a not in x and name_b not in x and name_c not in x:
            print sharpe
            print sharpes
            print portfolios
            print add_sharpe
            position = reverse_bisect(sharpes, sharpe)
            print position
            portfolios.insert(position, add_sharpe)
```

However, now I needed a reverse bisect (descending order). Thankfully, I found [a really good solution to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247394/python-bisect-it-is-possible-to-work-with-descending-sorted-lists).

The code to create a reverse bisect is as follows:

```
def reverse_bisect(a, x, lo=0, hi=None):
    if lo < 0:
        raise ValueError('lo must be non-negative')
    if hi is None:
        hi = len(a)
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo+hi)//2
        if x > a[mid]: hi = mid
        else: lo = mid+1
    return lo
```

It works very well when I was testing it out with simple calculations. However, when I plug it into my script, it causes the script to freeze at that point when being run. I have no idea why this is happening, as I am using the same logic as before with `bisect.bisect` which worked perfectly fine.

This is what is now not working:

```
        if name_a not in x and name_b not in x and name_c not in x:
            position = reverse_bisect(sharpes, sharpe)
            portfolios.insert(position, add_sharpe)
```

For some reason, using the function appears to loop over `portfolios.insert(position, add_sharpe)` without end.

The output:

```
[1, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6] #print portfolios
[[1], [0.9], [0.8], [0.7], [0.6]] #print sharpes
[1.6275936902107178, "CARR'S GROUP  (CARR.L)", 0.9, 'LSE  ', 'Church & Dwight Co. Inc. (CHD)', 0.05, 'NYSE  ', 'NCC Group plc. (NCC.L)', 0.05, 'LSE  '] #print portfolios
0 #print position
1.62759369021 #print sharpe
[1.6275936902107178, 1, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6] #print portfolios
[[1.6275936902107178, "CARR'S GROUP  (CARR.L)", 0.9, 'LSE  ', 'Church & Dwight Co. Inc. (CHD)', 0.05, 'NYSE  ', 'NCC Group plc. (NCC.L)', 0.05, 'LSE  '], [1], [0.9], [0.8], [0.7], [0.6]]
[1.6275936902107178, "CARR'S GROUP  (CARR.L)", 0.9, 'LSE  ', 'Church & Dwight Co. Inc. (CHD)', 0.05, 'NYSE  ', 'NCC Group plc. (NCC.L)', 0.05, 'LSE  ']
1
1.62759369021
[1.6275936902107178, 1.6275936902107178, 1, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6]
[[1.6275936902107178, "CARR'S GROUP  (CARR.L)", 0.9, 'LSE  ', 'Church & Dwight Co. Inc. (CHD)', 0.05, 'NYSE  ', 'NCC Group plc. (NCC.L)', 0.05, 'LSE  '], [1.6275936902107178, "CARR'S GROUP  (CARR.L)", 0.9, 'LSE  ', 'Church & Dwight Co. Inc. (CHD)', 0.05, 'NYSE  ', 'NCC Group plc. (NCC.L)', 0.05, 'LSE  '], [1], [0.9], [0.8], [0.7], [0.6]]
[1.6275936902107178, "CARR'S GROUP  (CARR.L)", 0.9, 'LSE  ', 'Church & Dwight Co. Inc. (CHD)', 0.05, 'NYSE  ', 'NCC Group plc. (NCC.L)', 0.05, 'LSE  ']
2
1.62759369021
[1.6275936902107178, 1.6275936902107178, 1.6275936902107178, 1, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6]
[[1.6275936902107178, "CARR'S GROUP  (CARR.L)", 0.9, 'LSE  ', 'Church & Dwight Co. Inc. (CHD)', 0.05, 'NYSE  ', 'NCC Group plc. (NCC.L)', 0.05, 'LSE  '], [1.6275936902107178, "CARR'S GROUP  (CARR.L)", 0.9, 'LSE  ', 'Church & Dwight Co. Inc. (CHD)', 0.05, 'NYSE  ', 'NCC Group plc. (NCC.L)', 0.05, 'LSE  '], [1.6275936902107178, "CARR'S GROUP  (CARR.L)", 0.9, 'LSE  ', 'Church & Dwight Co. Inc. (CHD)', 0.05, 'NYSE  ', 'NCC Group plc. (NCC.L)', 0.05, 'LSE  '], [1], [0.9], [0.8], [0.7], [0.6]]
[1.6275936902107178, "CARR'S GROUP  (CARR.L)", 0.9, 'LSE  ', 'Church & Dwight Co. Inc. (CHD)', 0.05, 'NYSE  ', 'NCC Group plc. (NCC.L)', 0.05, 'LSE  ']
3
```

Comment: What types are `sharpes` and `sharpe`?

Comment: Please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating the problem. Since we have absolutely no idea what `sharpes`, `sharpe`, `portfolios`, or `add_sharpe` are, there's no way we can help you.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid  added, my apologies...

Comment: Not an answer, but every time I need to write a bisection method, I end up copying this example implementation from C++: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/

Comment: @Juan Lopes thanks for the example. The code I have works well if you test it out. For example, if `l = [6,5,3,2,1]` and `reverse_bisect(l,4)` will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are inserting into the list you are iterating. For example:

```
a = [1]

for x in a:
    a.insert(0, x)
    print a
```

This will put you in a loop where you keep inserting `1` to `a`.

Comment: to be specific I am using `.insert()` but yes. Do you have any idea of how to simply add it once?

Comment: I can't tell from your code where any of the variables are coming from and why you are iterating over portfolios. Is the code you posted nested inside another loop?

Comment: I found the solution. I had to create a new list, and instead of inserting the value to the same list I was iterating over, I inserted it into the new list. Thanks for your help!