# Weird behaviour of bisect.insort in Python 3

Tags: python, sorting, insertion, bisection

`Python 3.8.2` on a linux box, If I create a `list` and just use `insort` over it, I get the expected result; on the other hand if I reverse the order of the elements in the container before calling `insort` this happens

```
>>> a = list(range(10))
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> a.reverse()
>>> a
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
>>> bisect.insort(a,6)
>>> a
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 6]
```

I was expecting `[9, 8, 7, 6, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]` not that.

Why it's producing this result ?

Comment: `bisect` needs a ordered list.

Comment: @Daniel `a` is ordered, it's just in reverse order

Comment: I assume that by sorted (as per the docs), it is meant: sorted in increasing order. The documentation for the various functions (and parameter names) also hint at this.

Comment: @00 if this is the case, that's a BIG hole in the docs ...

Comment: Sure. You could file an issue for that. But for the moment, I think this also the assumption you'll to work with.

Comment: You can also deduce it from [the code itself](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/bisect.py), linked in the docs. The code is even shorter than the full documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html):

> This module provides support for maintaining a list in **sorted**
>   order without having to sort the list after each insertion.

also from the docs:

> Unlike the sorted() function, it does not make sense for the bisect()
>   functions to have key or reversed arguments because that would lead to
>   an inefficient design (successive calls to bisect functions would not
>   “remember” all of the previous key lookups).

Comment: I don't think it's a valid answer/description . you can sort a bunch of numbers with the "less than" or "greater than" operator . That list IS sorted .

Comment: that list is reversed is a bit different

Comment: how is different from sorting with a "less than operator" ?

Comment: @xelp now my answer is better?

Comment: you may also havea look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247394/bisect-is-it-possible-to-work-with-descending-sorted-lists)

Comment: at this point I think they just forgot to mention the expected ordering ( ascending order ) in the docs and `insort` is only valid for ascending orders .