# How to efficiently do binary search on reverse sorted list in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, optimization

I want to do binary search on reverse sorted lists in Python. The list is appended in reverse order, and it has to be like this or else my code will break.

I need the code to be as fast as possible, assume the list is huge. I know Python code is slow so the code has to be compiled. And I know the `bisect` module in the standard library imports precompiled `_bisect` module if found, `_bisect` is implemented in C which is very fast.

However it doesn't work on reverse sorted lists, I tried `key = lambda x: -x` and it didn't work:

```
In [51]: l = range(50, 0, -5)

In [52]: from bisect import bisect

In [53]: bisect(l, 18, key=lambda x: -x)
Out[53]: 10
```

I copied code from the file from the installation and modified it:

```
def bisect_right(a, x):
    lo, hi = 0, len(a)
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo + hi) // 2
        if x < a[mid]:
            hi = mid
        else:
            lo = mid + 1
    return lo
```

Change `x < a[mid]` to `x > a[mid]` will make it work on reverse sorted lists.

```
def reverse_bisect(a, x):
    lo, hi = 0, len(a)
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo + hi) // 2
        if x > a[mid]:
            hi = mid
        else:
            lo = mid + 1
    return lo
```

The uncompiled code is much slower than precompiled code, as expected. Also note I cannot compare the performance of `reverse_bisect` against `_bisect.bisect` because the latter doesn't work properly in this case.

```
In [55]: %timeit bisect(range(0, 10**7, 10), 4096)
2.91 µs ± 97.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

In [56]: %timeit bisect_right(range(0, 10**7, 10), 4096)
5.22 µs ± 87.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

So I tried to compile the functions using `numba.jit`, I added `@numba.jit(nopython=True, fastmath=True, cache=True, forceobj=False)` to the line before `bisect_right`, producing `bisect_right_nb`, but `bisect_right_nb` gives me a warning and is ***SIX ORDERS OF MAGNITUDE SLOWER***:

```
In [59]: @numba.jit(nopython=True, fastmath=True, cache=True, forceobj=False)
    ...: def bisect_right_nb(a: list, x: int):
    ...:     lo, hi = 0, len(a)
    ...:     while lo < hi:
    ...:         mid = (lo + hi) // 2
    ...:         if x < a[mid]:
    ...:             hi = mid
    ...:         else:
    ...:             lo = mid + 1
    ...:     return lo

In [60]: l = list(range(0, 10**7, 10))

In [61]: %timeit bisect_right_nb(l, 4096)
C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\numba\core\ir_utils.py:2149: NumbaPendingDeprecationWarning:
Encountered the use of a type that is scheduled for deprecation: type 'reflected list' found for argument 'a' of function 'bisect_right_nb'.

For more information visit https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/deprecation.html#deprecation-of-reflection-for-list-and-set-types

File "<ipython-input-59-23a3cb61146c>", line 2:
@numba.jit(nopython=True, fastmath=True, cache=True, forceobj=False)
def bisect_right_nb(a: list, x: int):
^

  warnings.warn(NumbaPendingDeprecationWarning(msg, loc=loc))
1.66 s ± 11.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [62]: 1.66*10**6/5.22
Out[62]: 318007.66283524904
```

Just how can I improve the performance of `reverse_bisect_right`?

---

And no, I have read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69608002/16383578), I am not trying to insert the element into the list, I am trying to get rid of all elements smaller than it.

(And my network connection is unstable, my ISP is disrupting my VPN connection, so my update took so long.)

Comment: *"I tried key = lambda x: -x and it didn't work"* - Well you forgot to negate the search value (`18` in your example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't ignore warnings

```
Encountered the use of a type that is scheduled for deprecation: type 'reflected list' found for argument 'a' of function 'bisect_right_nb'.
```

If we adress that and use a `TypedList`, then we get a nice speedup:

```
l = nb.typed.List(list(range(0, 10**7, 10)))
%timeit bisect_right_nb(l, 4096)
1.14 µs ± 1.21 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
```

compared to

```
l = list(range(0, 10**7, 10))
%timeit bisect_right_nb(l, 4096)
753 ms ± 38.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: How much time does the creation of the typed list take? (Btw it's not really called `TypedList`, is it?)

Comment: The class is called `List`, in the `numba` docs it is referred to `typed-list` and it is implemented in `typedlist.py`. For the creation time: if I read the implementation correctly, it should be O(n), but I havn't benchamarked ot